# Using polymorphism in (Surface)UserControl?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, pixelsense

My (Surface)UserControls share a big amount of code. So I'd like to define an abstract super class where I can define this common code and behaviour.

But how do I define an abstract super class for a (Surface)UserControl? I tried to just subclass the code-behind file of a SurfaceUserControl, but then I get the following error:

```
Partial declarations of 'Prototype_Concept_2.views.DependencyExpander' must not specify different base classes  C:\Users\Roflcoptr\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Prototype_Concept_2\Prototype_Concept_2\views\DependencyExpander.xaml.cs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deriving from SurfaceUserControl (or SurfaceControl or SurfaceContentControl or SurfaceItemsControl as appropriate) is definitely a good thing because it will make it easier for consumers of your control to work with Surface events on them.  You are right though that this results in a lot of duplication of code.

When we were building the Surface SDK, a lot of automated code generation was employed to mitigate this issue.   If you use Reflector to look at how the Surface controls are implemented, you will see that there is very little logic built into the controls themselve
are a few helper classes which contain a ton of logic that gets leveraged by each of the individual controls.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your Xaml file is probably still starting with:

```
<UserControl x:Class="..."
```

However, if you derive your class from a different type (not `UserControl`, but `SurfaceUserControl`), then you're saying that the same class subclasses two classes.

While you can make a custom control, and subclass that, I personally find that this can be more problematic than expected.  I would recommend trying to handle this differently.

Instead of trying to create a single superclass for the UserControl, it's often easier to use encapsulation to delegate the responsibility to a single class.  Each UserControl can handle the shared behavior this way.  Alternatively, you could use a shared DataContext (or a shared hierarchy there).

Answer (score 0):

The base control which you derive the usercontrols from need not be a SurfaceUserControl. So create a templated custom control which can be derived from SurfaceContentControl and put most of the code to be shared on that base class.